# If/else javascript function not working every time

Tags: javascript

Setting up an if/else function in a Javascript snippet:

```
function compareStatus() {
  if(valueTruebutton === statusRandomrapper) {
    alert("Both status are true");
  } else {
    alert("Nah, those status are different");
  }
}
```

The two variables I use come from:

```
var valueTruebutton = document.getElementById("truebutton").value;
```

and

```
var rapperA = {firstName:"A$AP Rocky", image:"test.jpg", clip:"test.com", status:"true", smallthumbnail: "test.png"};
```

The true button comes from this line:

```
 <button id="truebutton" onclick="compareStatusTrueButton()" style="background-color: #4BCC92; border: none; font-size: 2em;" value="true">True</button>
```

Full code for reference is [here](https://github.com/malditojavi/rappers/blob/master/index.html). Basically I assign a value to 2 elements in the page and I try to compare the function. **Most of the times it works correctly, but sometimes it won't work.**

I have tried to debug it by printing in the console both values:

```
 console.log("randomRapper.name:" + randomRapper.firstName + ", randomRapper.status: " +  randomRapper.status + " valueTruebutton: " +  valueTruebutton + " valueFalsebutton: " +  valueFalsebutton )
```

And even added `typeof` to make sure the value has the same format. In the [[image: sample] I clicked the 'false' button which has 'false' value assigned, and even if the Rapper has a 'status = false' it won't detect both values as the same value.

*Edit: live page to see the issue live https://principal-audits-75550.netlify.com

*2nd Edit: Added console.log typeof, all of them are 'string' [image]

Comment: are both boolean? i mean both of the variable you comparing have same type?

Comment: Make sure you aren't comparing a string version of a boolean "true" against an actual primitive boolean of true

Comment: in var rapperA, use the boolean true instead of the string "true"

Comment: All of them are 'string', just added the console.log typeof in the live version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

In your code, you declare **two** values:

```
var statusRandomrapper = rappers[Math.floor(Math.random()*rappers.length)].status;
var randomRapper = rappers[Math.floor(Math.random()*rappers.length)];
```

`statusRandomrapper` is the status of a random rapper, and `randomRapper` is an object containing **a different rapper**.

So, when you go to check the value, you're checking against a different rapper.

### The Solution

What you need to do instead is this:

```
var randomRapper = rappers[Math.floor(Math.random()*rappers.length)];
var statusRandomrapper = randomRapper.status;
```

This code only makes one rapper (`randomRapper`), and then sets `statusRandomrapper` to be the `status` field of that object.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to choose one random rapper correctly, then you should do this as follows:

`var randomRapper = rappers[Math.floor(Math.random()*rappers.length)];
var statusRandomrapper = randomRapper.status;`

Reason: `Math.random`, as expected, provides a random value each time it's called. Since you have only 3 rappers at the moment, the results sometimes matched and sometimes did not. If you had a list of 1000 rappers, most often you'd get wrong results.

Comment: At the moment of writing. He's doing this:  

`
var statusRandomrapper = rappers[Math.floor(Math.random()*rappers.length)].status;
     var randomRapper = rappers[Math.floor(Math.random()*rappers.
`